Swap sell Raydium api
Why when im buy token its ok
But when i want to swap i get error
Token $PENGU

{   id: "d563cefe-e1ff-4272-ad6e-ca34f5066f6c",   success: false,
version: "V1",   msg: "UNKNOWN_ERROR", }

import { Transaction, VersionedTransaction, sendAndConfirmTransaction, TransactionSignature, Connection, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { NATIVE_MINT } from '@solana/spl-token';
import axios from 'axios';
import { fetchTokenAccountData, getKepair } from './utils';
import { API_URLS, publicKey, Raydium } from '@raydium-io/raydium-sdk-v2';
import config from './config.json';
import { sleep, getConnection, getRandomFloat } from './utils';
import global_config from '../token_config.json';
import BN from 'bn.js';

interface SwapCompute {
  id: string;
  success: true;
  version: 'V0' | 'V1';
  openTime?: undefined;
  msg: undefined;
  data: {
    swapType: 'BaseIn' | 'BaseOut';
    inputMint: string;
    inputAmount: string;
    outputMint: string;
    outputAmount: string;
    otherAmountThreshold: string;
    slippageBps: number;
    priceImpactPct: number;
    routePlan: {
      poolId: string;
      inputMint: string;
      outputMint: string;
      feeMint: string;
      feeRate: number;
      feeAmount: string;
    }[];
  };
}

const _tokenAccounts : { [owner : string] : any } = {};

export const apiSwap = async (mnemonic: string, data: Record<string, any>, connection : Connection, buy : Boolean) => {
  const owner = getKepair(mnemonic);
  let inputMint: string;
  let outputMint: string;
  let amount: BN;
  let tokenAccounts = _tokenAccounts[owner.publicKey.toBase58()];

  if (buy) {
    inputMint = NATIVE_MINT.toBase58();
    outputMint = global_config.tokenToSwap;
    amount = getRandomFloat(config.buyAmountSol[0], config.buyAmountSol[1]);
    console.log(`[${mnemonic}] buying ${amount} SOL`);
    amount = new BN(Math.floor(amount * 10 ** 9));
  } else {
    inputMint = global_config.tokenToSwap;
    outputMint = NATIVE_MINT.toBase58();
    if (config.sellSwapFull) {
      if(!tokenAccounts) {
       tokenAccounts = await fetchTokenAccountData(connection, owner);
      }
      // Находим аккаунт токена, который нужно продать
      const inputTokenAcc = tokenAccounts.find((a) => a.mint.toBase58() === inputMint);
      if (!inputTokenAcc) {
        console.error('Token account not found for the token you want to swap.');
        return;
      }
      // Получаем баланс токена
      amount = new BN(inputTokenAcc.amount);
      console.log(`[${mnemonic}] selling ${amount / 10 ** 9} tokens`);
    } else {
      amount = getRandomFloat(config.sellAmountToken[0], config.sellAmountToken[1]);
      console.log(`[${mnemonic}] selling ${amount} tokens`);
      amount = new BN(Math.floor(amount * 10 ** 9));
    }
    
  }
  
  const slippage = 0.5;
  const txVersion: string = 'V0';
  const isV0Tx = txVersion === 'V0';

  const [isInputSol, isOutputSol] = [inputMint === NATIVE_MINT.toBase58(), outputMint === NATIVE_MINT.toBase58()];

  if(!tokenAccounts) {
      tokenAccounts = await fetchTokenAccountData(connection, owner);
  }
  
  const inputTokenAcc = tokenAccounts.find((a) => a.mint.toBase58() === inputMint)
  //?.publicKey;
  const outputTokenAcc = tokenAccounts.find((a) => a.mint.toBase58() === outputMint)
  //?.publicKey;

  const { data: sellResponse } = await axios.get<SwapCompute>(
    `${API_URLS.SWAP_HOST}/compute/swap-base-out?inputMint=${inputMint}&outputMint=${NATIVE_MINT.toBase58()}&amount=${"1500".toString()}&slippageBps=${slippage * 100}&txVersion=${txVersion}`
  );

  const { data: swapTransactions } = await axios.post<{
    id: string;
    version: string;
    success: boolean;
    data: { transaction: string }[];
  }>(`${API_URLS.SWAP_HOST}/transaction/swap-base-out`, {
    computeUnitPriceMicroLamports: String(data.data.default.h),
    swapResponse: sellResponse,
    txVersion,
    wallet: owner.publicKey.toBase58(),
    wrapSol: false,
    unwrapSol: true,
    inputAccount: inputTokenAcc?.mint.toBase58(),
    outputAccount: NATIVE_MINT.toBase58(),
  });
  console.log(swapTransactions)
  // const { data: swapResponse } = await axios.get<SwapCompute>(
  //   `${API_URLS.SWAP_HOST}/compute/swap-base-in?inputMint=${inputMint}&outputMint=${outputMint}&amount=${amount.toString()}&slippageBps=${slippage * 100}&txVersion=${txVersion}`
  // );

  // const { data: swapTransactions } = await axios.post<{
  //   id: string;
  //   version: string;
  //   success: boolean;
  //   data: { transaction: string }[];
  // }>(`${API_URLS.SWAP_HOST}/transaction/swap-base-in`, {
  //   computeUnitPriceMicroLamports: String(data.data.default.h),
  //   swapResponse,
  //   txVersion,
  //   wallet: owner.publicKey.toBase58(),
  //   wrapSol: true,
  //   //isInputSol,
  //   unwrapSol: false,
  //   //isOutputSol,
  //   inputAccount: isInputSol ? undefined : inputTokenAcc?.mint.toBase58(),
  //   outputAccount: isOutputSol ? undefined : outputTokenAcc?.mint.toBase58(),
  // });
  // Добавьте эту проверку
  // if (!swapTransactions.data || !Array.isArray(swapTransactions.data)) {
  //   console.error('Invalid transaction data received from the API');
  //   console.error('Server Response:', swapTransactions);
  //   return;
  // }

  const allTxBuf = swapTransactions.data.map((tx) => Buffer.from(tx.transaction, 'base64'));
  const allTransactions = allTxBuf.map((txBuf) =>
    isV0Tx ? VersionedTransaction.deserialize(txBuf) : Transaction.from(txBuf)
  );

  console.log(`[${mnemonic}] total ${allTransactions.length} transactions`);

  let idx = 0;
  if (!isV0Tx) {
    for (const tx of allTransactions) {
      const transaction = tx as Transaction;
      transaction.sign(owner);
      try {
        const txId = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [owner], { skipPreflight: true });
        console.log(`[${mnemonic}] ${++idx} transaction confirmed, txId: ${txId}`);
      } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof Error && err.message.includes('Signature 3JD8yaVYQuawnhkAJp17mbrpo7QAknvnwYif8QAicavfRcNFM4KPfQvYuWj5JmAwZ6hSqsiJ8iULJ4z32bHnNnxk has expired: block height exceeded.')) {
          console.log(`[${mnemonic}] ${++idx} transaction sending failed, trying again...`);
          await sleep(1000);
          continue;
        }
        throw err;
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (const tx of allTransactions) {
      const transaction = tx as VersionedTransaction;
      transaction.sign([owner]);
        let transcationSended = false;

        // while(!transcationSended) {
          try {
            const txId = await connection.sendTransaction(tx as VersionedTransaction, { skipPreflight: false });
        const { lastValidBlockHeight, blockhash } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash({
          commitment: 'processed',
        });
        console.log(`[${mnemonic}] ${++idx} transaction sending..., txId: ${txId}`);
        await connection.confirmTransaction(
          {
            blockhash,
            lastValidBlockHeight,
            signature: txId,
          },
          'processed'
        );
        console.log(`[${mnemonic}] ${++idx} transaction confirmed`);
        // transcationSended = true;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        if (err instanceof Error && err.message.includes('Signature has expired: block height exceeded.')) {
          await sleep(1000);
          continue;
        }
      }
      // }
    }
  }
  sleep(config.sleepTime);
};

export default apiSwap;


I think the api requires ATA for the mint address of token you wish to swap. So in inputAccount and outputAccount, you need to pass tokenAccounts' address, rather than the mint address.

Can you provide code how to create Input account for some token and Output account for sol

need to pass tokenAccounts address, rather than the mint address.
